# What are the chances of (not) getting drafted to army

Tags: probability, combinatorics

My country has new law, which requires every male from 18 to 23 to be added to possible recruit list. The computer algorithm chooses randomly from 10% of those young men. That also means, that from 18 to 23 a person is put through this lottery six times in total. So what are the chances of not getting drafted to army?

Answer (score 2):

Each year you would have a probability of $\frac{9}{10}$ of not being drafted, and it seems that the years are independent, so $\left(\frac{9}{10}\right)^6 = 0.531441$ for 6 years.

Where is this question from? (;

Comment: I'm pretty sure this one's from real life

Comment: If so, I was wondering what country this is

Comment: I don't know about which country recently implemented this, but I know that South Korea, Israel, etc, have laws similar to this.

Comment: I'm Israeli and a randomized draft sounds very odd

Comment: The United States had a similar system in the '60s: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Draft_lottery_(1969).